# Rearranging and customizing woocommerce checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I need to modify the default woocommerce billing&shipping fields. I need to move some of them, set a different form-row-class and add a placeholder while removing the labels. My code is working but I am wondering if there is a cleaner solution aka if the code can be shortened and/or optimized. my code is

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'override_address_fields');
function override_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['first_name']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    $address_fields['last_name']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    $address_fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    $address_fields['company']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    $address_fields['postcode']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    $address_fields['city']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';

    return $address_fields;
}

add_filter( "woocommerce_checkout_fields", "reordering_checkout_fields", 15, 1 );
function reordering_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);

    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'rearrange_checkout_fields' ); 
function rearrange_checkout_fields( $checkout_fields ) {
    $checkout_fields['billing']['billing_country']['priority'] = 80;
    $checkout_fields['shipping']['shipping_country']['priority'] = 80;

    return $checkout_fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include your third function in the first one, so your code will be like:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'customize_default_address_fields', 20, 1 );
function customize_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['first_name']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    $address_fields['last_name']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    $address_fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    $address_fields['company']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    $address_fields['postcode']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    $address_fields['city']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';

    // Reorder billing and shipping "country" fields (on checkout page)
    if ( is_checkout() )
        $address_fields['country']['priority'] = 80; // Country

    return $address_fields;
}

add_filter( "woocommerce_checkout_fields", "customize_other_checkout_fields", 20, 1 );
function customize_other_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['placeholder'] = 'yxz';

    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-first'); // HERE
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['class'] = array('form-row-last');  // HERE

    unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);

    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks. I actually forgot the form-row-first and form-row-last . i can't get it to work though. i added $fields['billing_email']['class'][0] = 'form-row-first';
    $fields['billing_phone']['class'][0] = 'form-row-last';  to the second function but it did not work.

Comment: @Arkansas44 There are some errors in that code… I have updated my code with the right way. Try it it should work now.